# Web Audio Api integration with Web Speech Api - stream speaker/soundcard output to voice recognition api

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, speech

**Problem:**

Ideally I would acquire the streaming output from the soundcard (generated by an mp4 file being played) and send it to both the microphone and speakers.  I know I can use "getUserMedia" and "createChannelSplitter" (in the Web Audio Api) to acquire & split (based on Audacity analysis the original signal is in stereo) the user media into 2 outputs which leaves me with 2 problems.

1. `getUserMedia` can only get streaming input from the microphone
   not from the soundcard (from what I have read)
2. streaming output can only be recorded/sent to a buffer and not sent
   to the microphone directly (from what I have read)

*Is this correct?*

**Possible workaround - stalled**:

The user will most likely have a headset microphone on but one workaround I have thought of is to switch to the inbuilt microphone on the device and capture what comes out of the speakers and then switch back to the headset for user input.  However, I haven't found a way to switch between the inbuilt microphone and the headset microphone without asking the user every time.

*Is there a way to do this that I haven't found?*

*What other solutions would you suggest?*

**Project Explanation**:

I am creating a Spanish language practice program/website written in `html` & `javascript`.  An mp4 will play and the speech recognition api will display what it says on the screen (as it is spoken in Spanish) and it will be translated into english so the user hears, sees, and understands what is being said by the person speaking in the mp4.  Then the user will use the headset microphone to answer the mp4 person (often the inbuilt microphone doesn't give good enough quality for voice recognition - depending on the device - thus the use of the headset).

**flow chart** of my workaround using inbuilt microphone

```
mp4->soundcard-> Web Audio Api -> channel 1 -> user's ears

channel 2 -> microphone input-> Web Speech Api-> html->text onscreen
```

**flow chart** of ideal situation skipping microphone input

```
mp4->soundcard-> Web Audio Api -> channel 1 -> user's ears

channel 2-> Web Speech Api-> html->text onscreen -> user's eyes
```

**Another potential work around:**

I would like to avoid having to manually strip an mp3 from each mp4 and then have to try and sync them so the voice recognition happens as the mp4 person speaks.  I have read that I can run an mp3 through the voice recognition api.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there is not currently (12/19) a way to accomplish this on this platform with the tools and budget I have.  I have opted for the laborious way to do this which is setting up individual divs with text blocks to be revealed as the person is speaking on a timer.  I will still use the speech api to capture what the user says so the program can run the correct video in response.

Answer (score 1):

1. Switching between speaker and user headset is a definite no go.
2. Speech recognition software usually requires clean and well captured audio. So, if the sound is coming from speakers, the users microphone is not likely to pick it up very well. And if the user is using headphones, then there is no way for the microphone to capture the audio at all.
3. As far as I know, you cannot send audio files `Web Speech Api` directly (I may be wrong here)
4. `Web Speech Api` Is not supported by all browsers so that is a downside to consider too: https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition

What I would recommend is checking out Google's Speech to text API: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/

With this service you can send them directly the audio file and they will send back the transcription.

It does support streaming so you could have the audio transcribed at the same time it is playing. The timing wouldn't be perfect though.

Comment: Thanks, T, I looked at google's speech to text initially which works great but costs $$.  I am doing this on my own time with no budget (for fun basically - I am teaching spanish to a couple 5th graders).  In addition I think I can send the audio file directly to the Web Speech Api too so I don't think I need google.  I would just have to generate seperate audio files for all of my mp4s which I would rather not do.  I wonder if I could use a plugin for the browser to accomplish the same thing and just get the user to download it?